# Import book information through API into Google Sheet

Tags: api, google-sheets

I want to put my book collection into a spreadsheet.  Is there a way of having some columns autofill (e.g. with ISBN/ Dewey Decimal info) using some API?

I have managed to do things with Wordnik's API before and wondered if a similar thing is possible.

So if I put in title/ author, could the next cell autofill the rest? Or even get the whole book's info by just entering the ISBN?

Edit: I can access the API behind Worldcat and get this webpage: http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?title=outsider&author=camus&maxRecs=1

However, I can't seem to get a cell in Google Sheets to coerce the 'Author' and 'Title' of the book cleanly.

Comment: Where does the data you want to input come from?

Comment: @Cooper I was thinking maybe a site like Worldcat? This is what you get when you look for API and ISBN on Google: http://xisbn.worldcat.org/xisbnadmin/doc/api.htm

Comment: I'll have to look at this on my laptop but it certainly looks possible at this point.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks. OK -  I think I can clarify now I've been playing around with Worldcat's API for a bit. I can use it to generate a url but I don't know how to use Google Sheets to extract the author or title. What I get is this, which doesn't seem very 'IMPORTXML'-friendly:

    (see http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?title=outsider&author=camus&maxRecs=1 for an example)

Any idea how I can coerce a title / author out of it from the tags on the page? I think I am getting nearer to the drive of the initial question!

Comment: I recommend utilizing Google Apps Script [URLFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

Comment: @Cooper it does look like it might be able to. I've currently got as far as this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMIAORoWGZHCClqrNFVSSK8vmlvSql9Lt-AAXHHD9FQ/edit?usp=sharing
The only problem being (if you look in J12/J13) that the INDEX command isn't sufficient to capture the name/title data consistently across books.